# Drag Range Slider - How to add step and an element (comma) to the output

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [dragdealer.js](http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/) and this is what I have got so far:

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeMonk/535Pd/)

While dragging through the slide, it gives an output,

Question:
1) How can I add a "," (comma) to the output after hundreds unit while dragging?

```
-> Right now:-$ 4023
-> Required Output:- $ 4,023
```

2) How to implement *step* so that it shows output is in multiple of 100?

```
-> Required Output:- $ 4.100 (multiple of 100)
```

Here is my code:

**JS:**

```
$(function() {

  new Dragdealer('just-a-slider', {
    animationCallback: function(x, y) {
      $('#dragValue').text(Math.round(x * 15000));
    }
  });

  var availHeight = $('.content-body').outerHeight() -
                    $('.content-mask').outerHeight();
  new Dragdealer('content-scroller', {
    horizontal: false,
    vertical: true,
    yPrecision: availHeight,
    animationCallback: function(x, y) {
      $('.content-body').css('margin-top', -y * availHeight);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")` to add in the comma, and if divide your base by 100, ( = 150 ), you will step through in 100's and can append additional 0's onto your text output as required.

See fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/535Pd/4/

Answer (score 2):

I believe this question has already been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2901298/3509905), but with commas.

Replace the "," with "." and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Question: 1) How can I add a "," (comma) to the output after hundreds unit while dragging?

```
-> Right now:-$ 4023
-> Required Output:- $ 4,023
```

`4023/1000`

2) How to implement step so that it shows output is in multiple of 100?

```
-> Required Output:- $ 4.100 (multiple of 100)

var str = (4023/1000).toString().split('.');
str[1] = Math.floor(str[1]); //Looks like you want to round down. If not, use ceil() or round()
var out = parseFloat(str.join('.'));
```